# Colorpicker popup goes out of current view

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, styled-components, color-picker

How can I make my colorpicker pop-up detect if it doesn't fit and display it above the button instead? Currently it goes out of the current view. I would like to make it able to detect that it's out of current view and open above the button instead. [image]

Here's what I have so far:

```
const Picker = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
`;

const Swatch = styled.div`
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  cursor: pointer;
`;

const PopOver = styled.div`
  position: absolute; 
  z-index: 100;
  top: calc(100% + 2px);
  bottom: 20rem;
  left: 6rem;
  border-radius: 9px;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
`;

    <Picker>
      <Label>{label}</Label>
      {isOpen && (
        <PopOver ref={popover}>
          <HexColorPicker color={color} onChange={onChange} />
        </PopOver>
      )}
      <Swatch style={{ backgroundColor: color }} onClick={() => toggle(!isOpen)} />
    </Picker>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you open the popup, check to see if the `y` position plus the `height` of the rendered item is greater than the window's `screenHeight`. If it is, change the y-position or add a class that places the popover above the trigger button.

If the y-position is greater than the screenHeight before adding the popover's height, then you might need to subtract the `scrollTop` value from the y-position to get the appropriate position in screen coordinates instead of document coordinates.